# Adding if conditional logic in Salesforce Lightning HTML email templates

Tags: lightning, email-template, html

need to add the case description in the lightning email template if the case origin is "Website".

As it's currently not possible to use conditional statemements in email template in Lightning ([IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdiQDUAZ/allow-conditional-statemements-in-email-template-in-lightning)), what could be a work around to achieve this?

below code throws this error:

This template doesn’t support SML merge fields. Use the merge field picker to replace merge fields starting with "{!".: HTML Value

```
{!IF({!Case.Origin ="Website",Case.Description, "")}
```

or

```
{!IF(​​​​​​​ISPICKVAL(!Case.Origin} , 'Website'),{!Case.Description}, '')}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Lightning Email Templates:

Use a custom formula field on the Case  object called something like this

```
Description_When_Rendered_In_Email_Template__c
```

with value

```
IF (ISPICKVAL(Origin,'Website',Description,NULL)
```

then the template can use

```
{{{Case.Description_When_Rendered_In_Email_Template__c}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But description cannot be used in a formula field as its a rich text type.

Comment: ooh -- good point - then rather than formula field, use a regular field (hidden from layouts) that you sync/populate with a before insert/save trigger or flow. May require data migration of legacy values if you're emailing from legacy records.